# Inappropriate ioctl for device with python and wandbox API

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, ioctl

before you guys say this is a duplicate question.. its not. This is in python and im using the wandbox API. Heres my code

````py
@bot.command()
async def linux(ctx):
  ez= os.popen("wandbox -f test.py 2> /dev/stdout").read()
  print(f"```{ez}```")
````

Im trying to make a linux command (discord.py) that everybody can use. Im trying to use the wandbox API though, its not working as expected. The code is supposed to run the file test.py.. Heres the code for test.py

```py
import os
os.system("ls")
```

It should be returning with **prog.py** although im getting the error Inappropriate ioctl for device.

Comment: are you sure you've pasted everything? Where do you observing this error?

Comment: Please don't edit old questions to ask new ones. Just post a new question with the new topic!

Comment: @JoachimSauer It says I cant ask anymore questions

Comment: @legoboy: then trying to circumvent that ban by editing an old one into a new one is just going to make things worse. When you are question-banned you get extensive links that teach you what to do to get rid of that ban. Don't try to cheat the system.

Comment: @gokareless yes im 100% sure I pasted everything. The code that I attached is the part thats giving me an error